# Correctly importing and debugging external Java code in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I've downloaded Java source code and I want to import it as a project in Eclipse in order to set a breakpoint at a specific function. The project contains a compiled .jar which open a GUI.

The source code only contains a "build.xml" file without further "project" files. I've followed these steps in Eclipse:

- 1) File -> Import -> File System
- 2) Selected the "From directory" where files are located

Now the importer expects that I select an "Import into folder" to enable de Next button, which I have no idea what that means. Anyway I hit Browse to the import folder and a namespace appears in a tree list

- 3) Selected the "Into folder" to the displayed namespace in that tree
  list: **edu.cal.ws.projectname**
- 4) I proceed with setting the breakpoint in one of the java files and
  hit Run
- 5) I get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
at edu.cal.ws.projectname.ProjectMainClass.main(ProjectName.java:1581)
```

the instruction pointer is stopped at:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

without further information.

Any ideas or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help you with the compilation problem without details of the project you're trying to compile.

However, if all you want to do is to debug the downloaded project, then you can do that without compiling it yourself.

1. Install [JD-Eclipse](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse), a Java decompiler plugin for Eclipse.
2. Add the precompiled .jar to your build path.
3. Run it in Eclipse's debugger and step through the decompiled source code.

It's not perfect, but it will probably let you determine why that .jar is not doing what you want it to do.

Comment: As I've said, "I've downloaded the source code", so I don't need to decompile anything, it's the crappy Java world that makes a hell for just importing a project into the overrated Eclipse.